# How can I use glyphicons in input for validation with HTML?

Tags: html, validation

I need to put a glyphicon in the input for validation. For example I want to allow for phone numbers that are 10 numbers long. When a person inputs a phone number, a warning icon is displayed because the number is not 10 numbers long. An ok icon is displayed when the number is long enough.

The code is something like this I think (*telefon* means phone):

```
enter code here <ng-form role="form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 control-label">Telefon</label>
                <div class="input-group col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="vm.firma.telefon" ng-maxlength="4" placeholder="Telefon ...">
                    <span class="success">
                    <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle form-control-feedback" style="color:green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="danger">
                        <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign-circle form-control-feedback" style="color:red" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can play with css but try this site http://formvalidation.io/examples/html5/